# SQL query for index/primary key ordinal

Tags: sql, postgresql, ordinal

In our on-line contest system, there is a frequently changing table `standings` with integer columns `(user_id, score)`. Both are indexed with a unique constraint. Two kinds of queries are required:

1. Given a `score` not in the table, return the 1-based position that the score would occupy if it were inserted.
2. Given a `user_id` in the table, return the position of the corresponding score.

In both cases, position is with respect to score ascending: a new score smaller than all currently in the table will have position 1.

Here's the tough part: we probably can't afford a table scan. The table may have up to 10 million records, and we need to handle at least 40 queries per second.

How to do this in PostgreSQL?

I have a non-SQL solution in Berkeley DB that uses its logical record number-enabled B-trees. It easily has good enough performance. But we would like to get rid of the BDB by re-implementing with a PostgreSQL query. I have tried the obvious

```
select 1+count(*) from standings where score < ? limit 1;
```

This causes a table scan.

I expect the answer to be "no way" because the logical record number facility of BDB requires locking the entire B-Tree for each edit. To get O(log N) performance, it relies on leaf counts in each node. All these counts in the path to root must change with every edit; hence, the locking. Such locking is against the design principles of PostgreSQL and probably any multi-user database.

So if the problem can't be solved with PostgreSQL, confirmation of this is the next best result of this question.

Comment: Is the table read-only? Or only written at certain times / rarely? if yes, can you afford to add a column `position`?

Comment: No, it changes very frequently as people add contest entries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a regular table, there is not much you can do **in PostgreSQL 9.1. `count()` results in a table scan**, because indexes do not have visibility information. To verify the rows are not deleted in the meantime, PostgreSQL has to visit the table.

If the table is read-only (or rarely updated), you *could* add a row number to the table. Then a query like:

```
SELECT rownumber+1
FROM   standings
WHERE  score < ?
ORDER  BY score DESC
LIMIT  1;
```

With an index:

```
CREATE INDEX standings_score_idx ON standings (score DESC);
```

Would get the result almost instantly.
However, that's **not an option for a table with write load** for obvious reasons. So not for you.

---

The good news: one of the major new features of the upcoming **PostgreSQL 9.2** is just right for you: "**Covering index**" or "**index-only scan**". I quote the 9.2 release notes [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/release-9-2.html#AEN110235):

> Allow queries to retrieve data only from indexes, avoiding heap access
>   (Robert Haas, Ibrar Ahmed, Heikki Linnakangas, Tom Lane)
>
> This is often called "index-only scans" or "covering indexes". This is
>   possible for heap pages with exclusively all-visible tuples, as
>   reported by the visibility map. The visibility map was made crash-safe
>   as a necessary part of implementing this feature.

[This blog post by Robert Haas](http://rhaas.blogspot.co.at/2011/10/fast-counting.html) has more details how this affects **count performance**. It helps performance even with a `WHERE` clause, like in your case.

Comment: Thanks!  Now if Heroku (the target) will just implement 9.2!