# Berkeley DB on Heroku

Tags: heroku, rubygems, berkeley-db

Is there a way to use [Berkeley DB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/berkeleydb/overview/index.html)  from Ruby on Heroku?  I know about the [bdb](http://rubygems.org/gems/bdb) gem and a few similar.  But Berkeley DB must be installed as a library in advance for these to build.

I am only beginning to learn about Heroku deployment, so apologize if this question is naive. I'm thinking there may be a way to configure bdb as a new gem that includes the BDB sources for building in the cloud.  Or perhaps only a pre-compiled BDB static library?  Possible?

In case it's handy, this question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11623928/sql-query-for-index-primary-key-ordinal), where I described the problem that Berkeley DB is able to solve, but PostgreSQL can (apparently) not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that [Redis](http://redis.io/), which is available on Heroku, has functionality close enough to BerkeleyDB to meet my requirement.