# SQL store rate changing in time and SELECT rate valid for particular time instant

Tags: sql, postgresql

In SQL table person_rate we have stored a rate float value which changes in time. Columns:

```
id (serial, PK)
person_id (int)
date_from (date)
rate (float)
```

`(person_id, date_from)` is unique, because at most one change per day is allowed (maybe it could be a PK, but it's not important)

Rate value for given person_id is valid at time domain from `date_from` date to next record with succesive `date_from`, or to the infty future if there is no such record. Example:

```
id   person_id  date_from  rate
101  1          2011-01-01 100.0
145  1          2012-01-01 180.0
193  1          2012-05-01 140.0
```

Now I need a SELECT query which for each `person_id` returns a `rate` valid for some given $date. Let say for 2012-03-01 it's 180; for 2012-05-02 it's 140 and so.

Solutions I have tested:

1) condition `date_from <= $date` + use window function `rank() OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY date_from DESC` + in superselect `WHERE rank = 1`

2) similar to 1) but use `SELECT DISTINCT ON (person_id)` instead of limiting rank to 1

Both 1) and 2) does not perform well, EXPLAIN show that db needs to sort all records for each `person_id` and then limit to 1 first. Probably this type of query can't fully utilise index on `date_from`?

**IDEA** - add a `date_to` column, which will be a bit redundant, because the value will be "date_from of succesive record, minus 1 day" (or +infty if no succesive record). But the query then could be with `date_from <= $date AND date_to >= $date` - which probably would have a good performance with indexes on date_from and date_to.

But I'm a bit afraid how to manage the data integrity in this case - how to set up constraint that [ date_from .. date_to ] intervals for one person_id shoud not be overlapped?

What is the best solution for postgresql for this type of query? Load is most read, not much writes to the person_rate table. Typical query would internaly need to get a rate for each day in month...

Maybe this [SQL query for index/primary key ordinal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11623928/sql-query-for-index-primary-key-ordinal?answertab=votes#tab-top) with the new indexes on pg 9.2 can help somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `LEAD` to generate the `to_date` column

```
with scd_table (
    select  a.*  , 
            lead(from_date,1,to_date('31/12/9999','dd/mm/yyyy')) over (partition by a order by from_date asc) as to_date
    from    YOUR_TABLE a
)
select  * 
from    scd_table
where   :d >= from_date
and     :d < to_date
```

(this is oracle syntax but `lead` is ANSI standard)

i think you should reconsider your design - look for slowly change dimension tables. 
there allot of articles about other designs. the way you did it - you would always fetch the next from_date in order to get just one particular instance of a client so that a bit heavy on selects.

Comment: Thanks for that "slowly change dimension tables" it seems to be what I need, similar to IDEA I explained. Nonoverlapping constraint probably could be implemented using insert trigger.

Comment: triggers are poor design. you need to ask your self one important question - is your system making more DML or selects ? if your system makes more DML you might want to give up `to_date` because each update/insert will require two updates (current row , and the to_date of the previous one). if your system does more selects - you might want to consider paying the penalty during insert in order to ease select's. i'll give you a rule of thumb - *if you have triggers, synonym or too many views - you are doing some thing wrong*.

Comment: There will be almost no update/insert in compare to selects. So the two updates is definitely OK. I think about triggers probably only for checking consistency constraints, e.g. not to allow insert [from, to] interval which overlaps another one.

Comment: i would do it in the application during the insert process. triggers should really be used only for patching and maybe a log-on trigger (but this is only me). you got an undocumented function called `overlaps`. i'm not suggesting you use it but read about it because finding overlapping can be trickier then you might think (talking from experience).

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple query:

```
SELECT person_id, date_from, rate FROM person_rate where date_from in (SELECT MAX(date_from) FROM person_rate WHERE date_from <= 'provided Date' and person_id = provided_id)
```

To get all Person rates use.

```
SELECT a.person_id, a.date_from, a.rate FROM person_rate a JOIN (SELECT person_id, MAX(date_from) as date_from FROM person_rate where date_from <= 'provided Date') b ON(a.date_from = b.date_from and a.person_id = b.person_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/be03e/1)

```
select distinct on (person_id) person_id, date_from, rate
from person_rate
where date_from <= '2012-03-01'
order by person_id, date_from desc
```

If (person_id, date_from) is unique then create that index:

```
create table person_rate (
    id serial primary key,
    person_id int,
    date_from date,
    rate float,
    unique (person_id, date_from)
);
```

If that is already a production table alter it:

```
alter table person_rate add 
constraint constraint_name unique (person_id, date_from);
```

Do not forget to run `analyze person_rate` after that. It will only use the index if the right conditions are met. That includes a big enough table.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT person_id, rate FROM person_rate WHERE date_from <= '2012-05-02' ORDER BY date_from DESC LIMIT 0,1;
```

Where second digit of LIMIT is max person_id you want to use (for example LIMIT 0,5 for first 5 person_id) and date goes here: date_from <= '2012-05-02'