# Storing all loan (insert loan date, update return date) records in one table or 2 tables (with history) is better?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, oracle

a simple database design question has been bugging me for a while, thought I'll ask it here.

Suppose I have a database table, `"Loan"` with the following fields,

```
StudentIdentification, LoanDate, ReturnDate
```

This table is used track every student who has loaned something (not in the database).
Since every student can loan and return and loan again (but not loan multiple times without returning, a loan must be followed by a return), a composite primary key is

```
used: StudentIdentifcation and LoanDate
```

Is it better to store data this way or instead to have 2 tables,

```
table 1: Loan   ( StudentIdentification, LoanDate)
table 2: LoanHistory   ( StudentIdentification, LoanDate, ReturnDate)
```

in this case, Loan table's primary key is

```
StudentIdentification
```

and LoanHistory table's primary key is

```
StudentIdentification, LoanDate
```

Everytime the student returns, the record in "Loan" is moved to the "LoanHistory" table with the ReturnDate updated (done in a transaction).

Which is better?

Comment: haha, a programming idiot **with access to SO**, that's the difference

Comment: Really, my comment was deleted?! Did the moderator fail to notice that the OP's username was, in fact, "programming idiot"? Man, everyone is so touchy around here these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a single table, and then have a filtered index (SQL Server 2008+) or indexed view (SQL Server 2005-) to enforce that there is only a single row for each student with a `NULL` return date:

```
CREATE TABLE Loans (
    StudentID int not null,
    LoanDate datetime not null,
    ReturnDate datetime null,
    constraint PK_Loans PRIMARY KEY (StudentID,LoanDate),
    constraint CK_Loans_NoTimeTravel CHECK (LoanDate < ReturnDate)
)
```

Filtered index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_Loans_SingleOpen ON Loans (StudentID) WHERE ReturnDate IS NULL
```

Indexed view:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.Loans_SingleOpen_DRI
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT StudentID FROM dbo.Loans WHERE ReturnDate IS NULL
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_Loans_SingleOpen ON Loans_SingleOpen_DRI (StudentID)
```

(Assuming `dbo` is the appropriate schema - which is needed for `SCHEMABINDING`, which in turn is needed to create the index)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple SCD (slowly changing dimension) structure and use one table to store both current and historical data.

```
StudentIdentification, CreationDate, LoanDate, ReturnDate
```

the first two columns are the PK.

You can also add  an amount to indicate a loan or a return.

You might find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901223/sql-store-rate-changing-in-time-and-select-rate-valid-for-particular-time-instan/15901397#15901397) relvant

Answer (score 1):

Have a single table with the three columns is the simplest way to do this.  It allows you to answer questions like "How many students loaned something in March 2013?" easily.  If you have two tables, you would need to access both of them to answer that question because you effectively have an "open loans" and "returned loans" table.

It could be that your system is very interested in the currently open Loans.  They might be queried and updated often.  In this case, it will perform better if you have the currently active loans in one table, and you push off the history into a secondary table.  This is good if you need to keep alot of history but you rarely read it.

Comment: Yea you are right. It is indeed better to handle everything in one table unless there is a lot of crud on that table. Good suggestion

Answer (score 0):

To provide an accurate answer more info. about the application is needed.  For example, why not have a single table with StudentId and LoanDate, with a primary key of StudentId.  When loaned item is returned then delete that row.  Thus, no StudentId record then nothing is currently on loan.  This suggestion assumes that LoanDate is important for sending out late reminders.  If no late reminders are required then why even have the LoanDate?

If you need loan history which includes return date and loan date.  Then add a second history table to store rows as they are deleted off of the Loan Table with the addtional return date field.